# Submeter formulario com jQuery.Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery.validate

Quero criar um metodo parecido com o required do jQuery.Validate só para verificar se o *campo foi preenchido ou não*.

Pois o formulario é muito grande e não tem como ser preenchido de uma vez só então o usuario vai salvar e depois editalo novamente assim com esse metodo ele podera saber mais rapido o que falta ou não.

Criei um metodo que deu "certo" a validação mas ele não deixa submeter o formulario. O que posso fazer?

Comment: Você usa que linguagem em server-side? PHP ?

Comment: E qual o teu código atual para podermos ajudar a resolver o problema do mesmo?

Comment: Conseguiste resolver o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Se você está usando uma função javascript, provavelmente fez algo do tipo:

```
 <form onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

 function validateForm() {
     // logica para validar formulario
     if( ... )
     {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Nessa construção você precisa retornar um `true` para enviar o formulário. Se a sua função estiver quebrada, talvez não retorne nem `true` nem `false`, o que não iria enviar o formulário. Antes de retornar coloque um `alert` para verificar o resultado e ter certeza que não há furos no script.

Se você estiver escrevendo com o jquery validation pluggin, você precisa montar os objetos de forma correta. Certamente a função já faz este retorno corretamente para você.

Uma forma de construir manualmente seria:

```
// pode ser a forma abaixo, que já caiu em desuso, ou a mais atual ainda abaixo
//$( "#idDoFormulario" ).submit(function( event ) {
$( "#idDoFormulario" ).on("submit", function( event ) {

   // a função é chamada antes de enviar,
   //então você irá ver a mensagem antes de ir pro servidor
   alert( "Antes de enviar foi chamado." );

   // você pode usar alguma destas maneiras abaixo para impedir o envio
   event.preventDefault(); // impede a ação padrão, que é enviar o formulário
   return false; // também impede 

   // se você não retornar nada ou um true, o formulário é enviado
});
```